# Detect change of readyState with SSE

Tags: javascript, dom-events, server-sent-events

I am using HTML5 Server-Sent events:

```
SSEUpdate = new EventSource("update.php");
```

I want to detect when `SSEUpdate.readyState` changes. I've tried `.onerror`, but when I use `console.log(SSEUpdate.readyState)`, I always get `0`. I want to run my function when `readyState` changes to `2`.

Comment: There actually is a `readyState` in the spec, but I can't find `onreadystatechange` so it still seems it doesn't work quite like ajax, instead you can check the `readyState` property of the `event.target` inside the `onerror` or `onmessage` handlers, but generally you shouldn't really need to. Why would you need to know this anyway ?

Comment: I'm guessing you always get 0 cause you're not connecting to anything, setup a webserver and make sure update.php sends the right information. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

Comment: To echo adeneo's comment: why do you want to know? SSE is designed to auto-reconnect. And if you care about the cases where auto-reconnect won't happen, you probably want to do the job properly and implement a proper keep-alive message. (?)

Comment: SSE doesn't always auto reconnect when the computer returns from sleep. I'm not yet sure if I'll need it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a polling solution:

```
var SSECheck = setInterval(function() {
    if (SSEUpdate.readyState == 2) {
        clearInterval(SSECheck);
        // call to fn to restart sse
    }
}, 500);
```

Takes up to 0.5s to capture, but it does the job.